# Автоматическое закрытие страницы.

Tags: javascript, django

Автоматическое закрытие страницы после изменения или удаления, я как понимаю необходимо организовать  средствами JavaSctipts или ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 4):

Вам просто не нужно открывать новые окна, не придётся их и закрывать тогда. Пользователи сами решат, что и как им открывать.

Comment: Поддерживаю, просто открывайте нужные ссылки на текущей странице, если после каких-то действий нужно переместить пользователя с этой странице, используйте [redirect][1], если речь идет о джанго.


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect